# Shopify webhook URL is not triggered (PHP)

Tags: php, shopify, shopify-app

I have a Shopify store with no apps installed. My requirement is to update a remote database with order details when a Shopify order create event is triggered.

This is how I set the webhook in Settings > Notifications
[image]

I have prepared the remote server path to run the following code which writes a text to a text file to see if the webhook is triggered. However it does not writes to the file.

PHP (in remote server: [www.example.com/shopify](http://www.example.com/shopify))

```
file_put_contents('/var/www/shopify.txt', "retrieved: ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
```

What have I been doing wrong here? The webhook URL is not triggered when a test notification is sent.

Comment: Have you verified your script writes the expected debug output, when _you_ call it directly? What feedback does the above UI from the screenshot give you?

Comment: @CBroe Yes it writes the intended text to the text file when it is called directly on browser. Above screenshot test notification button shows "An example webhook request has been sent".

Comment: What do access and error log have to say, after you send a test notification?

Comment: The code you've posted are missing the closing parentheses for `file_put_contents()`, so if that is your actual code, it would error out. When posting code, please always make sure you copy/paste the actual code. If we rewrite it here, you can accidentally create other issues (like this), or you can fix a potential typo without realizing it, which makes it _very_ hard for us to help you narrow it down.

Comment: @M.Eriksson sorry it was a mistake in the question. fixed it here.